# Implementing tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: with a ALAssetRepresentation image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alassetslibrary

Here's my method inside of the `UITableViewDataSource` view controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"studentCell";

    StudentTableCell *cell = (StudentTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Never gets called
    }

    Student *student = self.studentList[indexPath.row];

    cell.nameFirst.text = student.nameFirst;
    cell.nameLast.text = student.portrait.assetURL;

    // Portrait
    CGImageRef portraitRef = [cell.portrait.image CGImage];
    CIImage *portraitImage = [cell.portrait.image CIImage];
    if (portraitRef == NULL && portraitImage == nil) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:student.portrait.assetURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef assetRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];
            if (assetRef) {
                [cell.portrait setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:assetRef]];
            }
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {}];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This works as expected for the first few rows that fit inside of the initial scroll position of the table.

But as I scroll down, `cell.nameFirst.text` change as expected, while `cell.portrait.image` gets recycled and starts **repeating** the images loaded inside of the first scroll position.

#### Questions

1. How do I make sure every `cell` has the appropriate image
2. Can `cell` every be `nil`?

Comment: Your custom cell is being reused (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`) so the images in the first cells created are still there when they are reused. In your custom cell's `prepareForReuse` method, set the portrait image to nil.

Comment: I've tried `prepareForReuse` before and it basically induced an infinite loop of image reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make sure every cell has the appropriate image is create dictionary and in cellForRowAtIndexPath: check value(image) in the dictionary object at key (I like use indexPath.row as a key). If it is set it up for the cell if it isn't call:

```
[library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:student.portrait.assetURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {...
```

and once image is downloaded add it to the dictionary with key (indexPath.row).
You should reload the cell when you download your image, just remember to do it on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update image whether it is set or not. Your code only sets the image if there isn't one already. Cells get reused as you scroll. So each cell needs to be updated with the image appropriate for the `indexPath`.

Also note that `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:`. It's asynchronous. This means you need to update the cell on the main thread once you get the image in the `resultBlock`.

```
cell.nameFirst.text = student.nameFirst;
cell.nameLast.text = student.portrait.assetURL;

// Portrait
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:student.portrait.assetURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef assetRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];
    if (assetRef) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.portrait setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:assetRef]];
        });
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {}];

return cell;
```

Comment: The `dispatch_async` crashes my app with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` address `0xc000000c`. How do I retain the cell until this is finished?

Comment: The cell might be displaying different content (or be totally gone) when your block returns. You need to remember your index path, and ask the table for the current cell at that index path.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to utilize an image cache. Suppose the image cache has the following API:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result, NSError* error);

@interface SimpleImageCache : NSObject

/**
 Returns the image for the specified URL if it exists, otherwise nil.
 */
- (UIImage*) imageWithURL:(NSURL*)url;

/**
 Asychronounsly loads the image from the asset library. The compeltion handler will
 be called when the image is available or when an error occured.
 
 The execution context where the compeltion handler will be executed is 
 implementation defined.
 */
- (void) loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;

@end
```

In your code you would use it as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"studentCell";
    StudentTableCell *cell = (StudentTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Never gets called
    }
    Student *student = self.studentList[indexPath.row];
    cell.nameFirst.text = student.nameFirst;
    cell.nameLast.text = student.portrait.assetURL;
    // Portrait
    
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:student.portrait.assetURL];
    UIImage* portrait = [self.imageCache imageWithURL:url];
    if (portrait == nil) {
        portrait = self.placeholderImage;
        [self.imageCache loadImageWithURL:url completion:^(id image, NSError*error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                StudentTableCell* cell = (StudentTableCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                [cell.portrait setImage:image];
            });
        }];
    }
    [cell.portrait setImage:portrait];    
    return cell;
}
```

---

#### Implementation of `SimpleImageCache`

**Warning:** It's not tested, but it might give you a jump start, or an idea.

```
@interface SimpleImageCache ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* missingImage;
@end

@implementation SimpleImageCache {
    dispatch_queue_t _sync_queue;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _sync_queue = dispatch_queue_create("sync_queue", NULL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*) images {
    if (_images == nil) {
        _images = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return _images;
}

- (ALAssetsLibrary*) assetsLibrary {
    if (_assetsLibrary == nil) {
        _assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    }
    return _assetsLibrary;
}

- (UIImage*) imageWithURL:(NSURL*)url {
    __block UIImage* image;
    dispatch_sync(_sync_queue, ^{
        id obj = self.images[url];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            image = obj;
        }
    });
    return image;
}

- (void) loadImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url completion:(completion_t)completionHandler {
    dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
        if (self.images[url] != nil) {
            return;
        }
        self.images[url] = @"pending";
        [self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
            ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            __block  UIImage* image = CFBridgingRelease([representation fullResolutionImage]);
            dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
                if (image == NULL) {
                    image = self.missingImage;
                    NSAssert(image, @"image is nil");
                }
                self.images[url] = image;
                if (completionHandler) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                        completionHandler(image, nil);
                    });
                }
            });
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            if (completionHandler) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                    completionHandler(nil, error);
                });
            }
        }];
        
    });
}

@end
```